# Depth First Search & String index out of range:-3

Tags: java, depth-first-search, indexoutofrangeexception

Using a GraphRead-Class I didn't write myself, I'v to complete a Depth First Search Algorithm To edit graphs from text files.

This is how the class looks like:

```
public class GraphRead {

    public static Graph<Vert,Edge<Vert>> FileToGraph(String dat, boolean directed, boolean standardIds, boolean weighted) {
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        Graph<Vert,Edge<Vert>> G = null;
        try {
          fis = new FileInputStream(dat);
        }
        catch ( Exception e) {
            System.out.println(dat + " couldn't be opened");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        try {
              InputStreamReader isr   = new InputStreamReader(fis);
              BufferedReader    br = new BufferedReader   (isr);

              // read number of vertices
              String aRow;
              aRow = br.readLine();
              int n = new Integer(aRow);

              // read number of edges
              aRow = br.readLine();
              int m = new Integer(aRow);

              // construct graph
              G = new Graph<Vert,Edge<Vert>>(n, directed);

              if (!standardIds) { // vertices have arbitrary ids and get a name
                  // read vertices (1. substring: id, 2. substring: name)
                  for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
                      aRow = br.readLine();
                      int sepIndex1 = aRow.indexOf(' ');
                      String vId = aRow.substring(0, sepIndex1);
                      String vStr = aRow.substring(sepIndex1+ 1, aRow.length());
                      int id = new Integer(vId);
                      Vert v = new Vert(id,vStr);
                      G.addVertex(v);
                  }
              }
              else {
                // add vertices with standard ids (0 .. n-1)
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    G.addVertex(new Vert(i));
                }
              }
              // read edges with weight
              if (weighted) {
                  for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
                      aRow = br.readLine();
                      int sepIndex1 = aRow.indexOf(' ');
                      int sepIndex2 = aRow.indexOf(' ', sepIndex1+1);
                      String vStr = aRow.substring(0, sepIndex1);
                      String uStr = aRow.substring(sepIndex1+ 1, sepIndex2);
                      String wStr = aRow.substring(sepIndex2+ 1, aRow.length());
                      int vId = new Integer(vStr);
                      int uId = new Integer(uStr);
                      int w = new Integer(wStr);

                      Vert v = G.getVertex(vId);
                      Vert u = G.getVertex(uId);

                     G.addEdge(new Edge<Vert>(v,u,w));
                  }
              }
              else { // read edges without weight; 
                  for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
                      aRow = br.readLine();
                      int sepIndex1 = aRow.indexOf(' ');
                      String vStr = aRow.substring(0, sepIndex1);
                      String uStr = aRow.substring(sepIndex1+ 1, aRow.length());
                      int vId = new Integer(vStr);
                      int uId = new Integer(uStr);

                      Vert v = G.getVertex(vId);
                      Vert u = G.getVertex(uId);

                     G.addEdge(new Edge<Vert>(v,u));
                  }  
              }
            fis.close();
          }
          catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Reading was not successful");
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
          } 

        return G;   

    }
}
```

I always get a "String Index out of range-3"-exception.
 And I've no idea why.

The file has the following format: 
1. row: number of vertices (n)
2. row: number of edges (m)
The ids of the vertices and the name of the vertices are separated by a blank.
The subsequent m rows: start- and endvertex of the edge and the weight of the edge (only if weighted = true), are separated by blanks.
The parameter "directed" is true if the graph is directed.
In case it is directed: each edge e = (a,b) in "dat" is only added to the adjacency list of the variable a.
In case it is not directed: each edge e = (a,b) is added into the adjacency list of variable a and in the adjacency list of variable b. 
The parameter "standardIds" is true if the vertices have ids between 0 and n-1 and no names.
The parameter "weighted" is true if the edges are weighted.

The content of a Graph-txt looks like this:

```
9
11
0 1
0 4
1 2
2 5
5 3
3 2
3 0
3 4
6 3
7 6
8 7
9
```

Any idea how I can solve this ? Thank you !

Comment: Could you please add exception's stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs at this line

```
String uStr = aRow.substring(sepIndex1+ 1, sepIndex2);
```

and the reason is because there are only (max) 2 numbers in a line in your file and thus only one space the following will set `sepIndex2` to -1 since `sepIndex1` is 1

```
int sepIndex2 = aRow.indexOf(' ', sepIndex1+1);
```

---

For clarity, this is what I used when testing this.

The final version of the input file

> 9
>   2
>   0 1
>   0 4
>   1 2
>   2 5
>   5 3
>   3 2
>   3 0
>   3 4
>   6 3
>   7 6
>   8 7

And my version of the code where I removed any references to unknown classes such as `Graph` etc and also some other edits. This was done since I was only interested in the logic regarding reading of the file

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GraphRead.FileToGraph("~/temp/graf.txt", true, false, false);
}

public static void FileToGraph(String dat, boolean directed, boolean standardIds, boolean weighted) {
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(dat);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(dat + " couldn't be opened");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

        // read number of vertices
        String aRow;
        aRow = br.readLine();
        int n = new Integer(aRow);

        // read number of edges
        aRow = br.readLine();
        int m = new Integer(aRow);

        if (!standardIds) { // vertices have arbitrary ids and get a name
            // read vertices (1. substring: id, 2. substring: name)
            System.out.println("!standardIds");
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
                aRow = br.readLine();
                int sepIndex1 = aRow.indexOf(' ');
                String vId = aRow.substring(0, sepIndex1);
                String vStr = aRow.substring(sepIndex1 + 1, aRow.length());
                int id = new Integer(vId);
                System.out.println(vId + ":" + vStr);
            }
        }

        // read edges with weight
        if (weighted) {
            System.out.println("weighted");
            for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
                aRow = br.readLine();
                int sepIndex1 = aRow.indexOf(' ');
                int sepIndex2 = aRow.indexOf(' ', sepIndex1 + 1);
                String vStr = aRow.substring(0, sepIndex1);
                String uStr = aRow.substring(sepIndex1 + 1, sepIndex2);
                String wStr = aRow.substring(sepIndex2 + 1, aRow.length());
                System.out.println(uStr + ":" + wStr);
            }
        } else { // read edges without weight;
            System.out.println("!weighted");
            for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
                aRow = br.readLine();
                int sepIndex1 = aRow.indexOf(' ');
                String vStr = aRow.substring(0, sepIndex1);
                String uStr = aRow.substring(sepIndex1 + 1, aRow.length());
                System.out.println(vStr + ":" + uStr);
            }
        }
        fis.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Reading was not successful");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx Joakim. So how should change the line ?

Comment: You will avoid the the error by calling the method with `weighted` set to `false` since you don't have weights in your file (?) but it looks like you get an exception with the last row then since it's single digit. Are you sure that line is correct?

Comment: I guess the last line was a mistake. I deleted it. But I still get this message: _"Reading was not successful
null"_

Comment: Worst case: maybe somebody knows how to alter the class, so I can work with the txt file ?

Comment: @me4gqp First of all let me say that the class you have is not very well written and the code is very fragile. I managed to run it properly by setting m (row 2) to 2 instead of 11 because that is how I interpret the code, you have `x` lines with values in the file and `x` = `n` + `m` then the `n` first rows are handled in the first loop and the last `m` lines is handled in the second loop

Comment: @Joakiam: I agree. Guess I'd be faster If I write myself a GraphRead. But I've to use this particular class....Okay I changed the row2 in the txt file to 2 instead of 11, but I still get _"Reading was not successful null"_ Any further suggestions ?

Comment: @me4gqp Not really since it works for me with the file and the parameters used in my answer. Most likely the exception comes from some of the other related classes since I don't get an error. You could add `e.printStackTrace();` inside the `catch (Exception e) {} clause at the end and post the result

Comment: here is the printStackTrace(): _"java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Edge.<init>(Edge.java:21)
 at GraphRead.FileToGraph(GraphRead.java:90)
 at test.main(test.java:64)"_

Comment: So the error occurs when creating a new Edge object and so I have no idea what happens in the Edge constructor, you need to debug this yourself.

Comment: I did so. FINALLY it reads the file ! ! ! ! 
Now I have to edit three txt files with the dfs search. I was given the expected results and they deviate. -.- First of all, I try to solve the problem alone. Otherwise, it's best to open another threat. Thank you for your help.